# smart doorbell chime module to actuate ac relay

Tags: ac, relay

I'm looking to get an Amcrest AD110 video doorbell and just looking for clarification on hooking it up to my existing (ancient) electronic musical chime.

My current setup looks like this...
[image]

The Amcrest doorbell requires up to 24v AC which is more than my chime box currently uses; I don't know how tolerant it would be of higher voltages but I don't want to damage it or shorten its lifespan. Following that, I was hoping to add another 24v ac supply to power the AD110 and then use a relay to keep both circuits separate. Would the following diagram work? ie. would the amcrest chime module be able to actuate an AC relay directly (which would in turn trigger the input on the chime box)?
[image]

When looking at relays I found [THIS](https://cpc.farnell.com/schrack-te-connectivity/rt114524/relay-pcb-spco-24vac/dp/SW03364) which I think fits the bill?

Comment: Does your new doorbell work with just 2 wires or does it have an additional wire for power?  What you need is a datasheet/wiring diagram for the new doorbell module so you can figure out how it's meant to control its output.

Comment: Yes, the above wiring is as per the manual. The amcrest unit is designed to be a drop-in replacement for old school doorbell setups that are usually just the transformer, switch and mechanical chime wired in series. As the AD110 requires constant power, the chime module (I believe) has a normally low resistance to stop your mechanical chime from buzzing continuously and then exhibits a high resistance whenever the AD110 button is pushed which actuates the chime like normal. I'm just not sure if I can have the chime module actuate an ac relay instead.

Comment: Well the doorbell has to draw power at some point, so there may be a small constant current to power the camera and electronics, so as long as the current was small, that would be the high resistance period and when you pressed the button it would go low resistance and pass current through to power the chime.  That makes more sense to me.  As long as your button module and transformer pass enough power to energise the relay it would work, although their chime module might not like being in parallel to an inductive load like a relay.

Comment: Assuming it works that way, you'd want a 24v relay that didn't have too much volt drop and didn't actuate at the low current level and did actuate at the high current level.  Either way it would be wise to use a voltmeter to confirm the working of the intended circuit before you try to add anything to it.  Is it intended that you can use a traditional doorbell chime instead of the module they provide if you want?  That would be a good sign.

Comment: Is it intended to work with a traditional doorbell chime or only the chime kit they provide?